# I accidentally git reset one commit too far. How do I undo this?

Tags: git, github

Quick preface, I have very little experience with git and other console based programs.

That being said, the problem at hand is that I used `git reset --hard HEAD~` to roll back to a previous commit due to some corruption, but I ended up going one commit too far. Is there any way to undo the rollback or go forward a commit? I haven't synced it to the web yet.

Comment: Here are some other options for you as well:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revet-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git reflog | head` should show you the commit ids you need to recover your lost commit.

```
xxxxxxx HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~
yyyyyyy Your lost commit?
```

You can try the following

```
git checkout yyyyyy -b newbranch
git log newbranch
```

or

```
git cherry-pick yyyyyy
```

Answer (score 5):

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

This takes you back to before you reset wrong, assuming only ONE commit too far. From there you can reset again to the correct commit.

```
git reflog
```

Use this to see a list of updates. Each update is assigned with a HEAD number (for example, HEAD@{1}: reset: blah..blah..), you use this number to point to where you want to go just like the first command.

Comment: This worked well for me and seems simpler than the accepted answer. Generic: `git reset HEAD@{x}` - x being the number of commits you've gone too far. Though I haven't tried this with a hard reset, only after doing `git reset HEAD~y`.